# Is there a way to perform the YouTube full screen action programmatically without stopping playback?

Tags: android, youtube-api

I am wondering if there is a way of doing the YouTube full screen action (showing in landscape mode only the player) programmatically in android? I tried `YouTubePlayer.setFullscreen(true)` but that causes the playback to stop I am clueless of where to start.

Answer (score 1):

Simply call `YoutubePlayer.setFullscreen(true)`. You can find the reference in the official `YouTubePlayer` [docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer#setFullscreen(boolean)).

There are a couple things of importance to note here:

> Calling this function may affect the **looks of the player's controls**, e.g. showing an option to enter or exit fullscreen, changing the layout to better suit the current player size etc.

and

> Calling this function will cause any registered [YouTubePlayer.OnFullscreenListener](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer.OnFullscreenListener) to fire

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I already knew that. What I meant was to manually put the player in landscape mode, without calling YoutubePlayer.setFullscreen(true)... I need that because changing to full screen stops the video, so I try to bypass that.

Comment: You should've made that clear in your question. You can still do that, Put your player in a container, e.g. `RelativeLayout`, `LinearLayout` etc. change the container's width and height to fixed to make the screen smaller or `match_parent` to make it full screen. This container should be placed on the topmost layer on your `Activity`'s layout.

Comment: Ok thanks I understand, but how to make the player go sideways like it does when you watch fullscreen videos on youtube?

Comment: You should animate the layout changes. BTW that answer deserves a different question on its own.

Comment: @ItayGutlansky Also you should edit the question to include **programmatically** and **already tried setFullscreen(true)**.

Comment: Changed it as you said. What you are saying about animating the layout changes sounds quite difficult. Perhaps you have any idea of how to set full screen mode on a player without making it stop?

Comment: You can get started with [Custom Transitions](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/custom-transitions#java). I already told you how you can change to full screen without stopping the player.

Comment: @ItayGutlansky Try adding flags `FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_ORIENTATION` or `FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CUSTOM_LAYOUT` by calling `ytPlayer.addFullscreenControlFlag();`. This should stop starting playback on setting the player to full screen.

Comment: Also make sure your `Activity` is not recreating on orientation change.